# Will my code run faster with minimum amount of variables?

Tags: c++, optimization

let's say as an example that we have two types of code :

FIRST:

```
float calculateAComplicatedValue(float x,float y)
{
    int XasInt = floor(x);
    int YasInt = floor(y);

    float uniqueValueFrom2Numbers = ((x+y) * ((x+y)+1) / 2 ) + y;
    float lerp = 0.5f * (y - x) + x;

    float finalValue = ((XasInt * YasInt) + (uniqueValueFrom2Numbers / 2)) * lerp;
    return finalValue;
}
```

SECOND:

```
float calculateAComplicatedValue(float x,float y)
{
    return ((floor(x) * floor(y)) + ((((x+y) * ((x+y)+1) / 2 ) + y) / 2)) * 0.5f * (y - x) + x;
}
```

Which one will run faster and why ? and is the difference big enought to consider ?

Comment: Have you looked at the assembly to see if there's any difference? Have you run the code to measure the time difference?

Comment: In general no.  In your first example the compiler probably optimizes away unneeded variables and/or changes them to registers.  In your second example it creates variables (or uses registers) to hold in-between results.

Comment: Handy reading: [The As-If Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). TL;DR version: The compiler can to whatever it wants to make your code faster so long as it doesn't change the program's observable behaviour. Note that in some cases the compiler can leave you with effectively no program.

Comment: 99+% of code does not need to be optimized (by hand - let the compiler do it).  In real-world code being maintainable is ten times as important.  If there is ever a bottleneck that matters then the 1% requires profiling and optimizing, which is more likely to mean finding a better algorithm than trying to be a human compiler.

Comment: @Ronald joe just just ignore comment, instead of writing back, that won't resolve question....

Comment: My apologies for seeming aggressive, that was not my intent. If you are a beginner, then you should definitely not worry about this kind of micro optimization. Try and write the code that is most readable for you, and trust the compiler to take care of optimizing it.

Comment: @Ronald "why so agressive ?" - I seen *nothing* aggressive in the comment by cigien . He/she just asked a fair question "Have you looked at the assembly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The number of variables you use will (generally) not matter. Once you turn on your compilers optimizer it will figure out how to remove the intermediate unnecessary variables and the end result will be the same.

For an unoptimized (debug) build (which is the default for most compilers), there may be a *tiny* difference, but it shouldn't matter for your day-to-day coding and it certainly won't matter for the final product since you wouldn't ship debug builds to customers - right?